# The first line in Output

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the first char in one line, then the first two chars in the next line etc. of a string.

I do not understand the reason for a blank line in the beginning and why the last line did not complete the word. I was able to get the desired output by a change in for loop to (i=1 and i<=k).

```
public class Tester6 {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    int k = userInput.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.println(userInput.substring(0,i));
    }
  }
}
```

The output for the input four is,

f
fo
fou

Comment: Index start from 0. First time in loop, It will print empty string as you are printing string which start from 0 to 0 ("from" and "to" both are zero.). In last iteration, you will not have last char as you are put length as index value. Length and index two diff thing; but are connected to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the substring (0,0) is "". As the [`String.substring(int, int)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) says (in part)

> The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.

That is why you get a blank line with `i` at `0`. And why you don't get the last character when `i` is at the last character. You could adjust your call to `substring` with `+ 1` like

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    System.out.println(userInput.substring(0,i + 1));
}
```

Comment: So `substring(0, 0)` would start at index 0 (zero) and extend to index -1 (minus one), wouldn't it?

Comment: No. Because it **extends** to `endIndex - 1` - which means it returns the characters between `0` and `0`. Which is `""`.